# how to disable shell flyout(menu items) zomming on click in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, flyout

i am using shell project in xamarin forms , i am facing issue when i click on bottom flyout menu , it is zooming and some text not disables on selected flyout menu.eg Home becomes Ho.

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO Shatrughna! Apart from the code that's not working properly, if you could also share screenshots of what you have, that would help us!